# Checking data between two dates using cobol

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am new to cobol programming. I want to check and process data between two dates for certain transactions  i.e. From-date and to-date using cobol. I have data in flat file. from-date and to-date are part of the data.So For certain account number, there are transactions for each year. I want to read these transaction starting from from-date until to-date and update some of their fields. Could you please help me with the issue.

Comment: It depends a great deal on what you intend by "check and process". Please include more information.

Comment: In particular, please show how dates are represented in your COBOL program.  MMDDYYYY?  YYYYMMDD?  Something else?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Dates represented as YYYYMMDD

Comment: What have you tried so far and didn't work?

Comment: Are the format for the data all character (EBCDIC) or numeric of some type?  It also sounds like the data is pre-sorted by account number ... is that correct?

Comment: Solution depends also of data volume.
If your file is less than a thousand lines, you can access it in a linear way, just checking each record is between dates and update data.
On the contrary, if you must deal with large record number, I would strongly advise to pre-sort the file (which I would do in the JCL) and then seek beginning record using dichotomic search and then proceed in sequence until last record to process. Then eventually re-sort if needed.

Answer (score 2):

For setting for the from and until date, I would recommend either passing it as a parameter in the JCL, or putting those dates in a file. once you have access to those dates in the program, the processing will look something like this:

```
WS-FROM-INT  = FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DAY (FROM-DATE)
WS-UNTIL-INT = FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DAY (UNTIL-DATE)

PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-FILE
   WS-TRANS-INT = FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DAY (TRANS-DATE)

   IF (WS-TRANS-INT >= WS-FROM-INT) AND (WS-TRANS-INT <= WS-UNTIL-INT)
      do whatever processing you want
   END-IF
END-PERFORM
```

Changing the date to integers makes the comparison a lot easier. Here is some documentation about the INTEGER-OF-DATE function: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPSQF_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/c0925395610.htm